# Question on pin management using PCA9534PW IO Extender

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, pins, c

There is an IO expander [PCA9534PW](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/NXP-Semicon-PCA9534PW-118_C161197.pdf), Arduino UNO. I don’t really understand how I can manage this expander using UNO over I2C.

I found an [example](http://diy-scib.org/content/pca9534-io-expander), but here is the reading mode.

What I need:
Set the IO0 pin to exit mode,
set the HIGH / LOW level to IO0.

In the datasheet, I just realized that to enter the settings mode - you need to write Wire.write(0x03).
How can I do it?

Comment: Hint: There is more or less always someone that has done this before you, and shared it. Please see, for instance, https://github.com/alotaiba/PCA9534.

Comment: Answer: Write to the configuration register to set the pin mode. See https://github.com/alotaiba/PCA9534/blob/master/src/PCA9534.cpp#L14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the pin mode by setting the configuration register.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
Wire.write(0x03);                   // Configuration Register
Wire.write(0xfe);                   // IO7-IO1 Input, IO0 Output
Wire.endTransmission();
```

Then write the output port register with HIGH and LOW.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
Wire.write(0x01);                   // Output Port Register
Wire.write(0x01);                   // IO0 HIGH
Wire.endTransmission();
delay(500);
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
Wire.write(0x01);                   // Output Port Register
Wire.write(0x00);                   // IO0 LOW
Wire.endTransmission();
```

But using a library is much easier. See, for instance, https://github.com/alotaiba/PCA9534.

Comment: Many thanks for the example! I have seen this library, but it does not compile under Arduino. https://github.com/alotaiba/PCA9534/issues/1

Comment: It should be very easy to port from Particle. Have you tried to comment out this line, https://github.com/alotaiba/PCA9534/blob/master/src/PCA9534.h#L14, or just create an empty file with the name "Particle.h".